# Django メール機能、ロリポップとの連携

Tags: python, django

Djangoのメール認証機能を実装したいです。ロリポップのメールサーバーにアクセスしてメールを送りたいと考えております。

`settings.py`、ならびにメール送信機能が書かれている`account/views.py`は次のように実装しました。`EMAIL_HOST_USER`等の情報はロリポップのユーザー専用ページにて確認しました。

しかしながら下記の実装では`SMTPServerDisconnected at /account/signup/` というエラーが返ってきます。おそらくSMTPサーバーに接続できていないのだと思います。どこに問題がございますでしょうか？

`settings.py`

```
# Email Settings
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.lolipop.jp'
EMAIL_PORT = '465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@test.com'
```

`accounts/views.py`

```
# Send email
template = get_template('emails/signup.html')
content = template.render(Context({'onetime_code': user.onetime_code}))
subject = 'test'
from_email = 'info@test.com'
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject,
    content,
    from_email,
    [user.email]
)
email.attach_alternative(content, "text/html")
email.send()

return redirect('/invoice')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

telnet等で対象のメールサーバー smtp.lolipop.jp にポート465で接続できることを確認済みであることを前提として、回答します。

ロリポップの公式ドキュメントより、ロリポップのメールサーバーにはSMTP−AUTHが使用されているようです。
https://lolipop.jp/manual/mail/mail-server/

Djangoのメール送信の仕組みでSMTP-AUTHを使用するには、 EMAIL_USE_TLSではなく、EMAIL_USE_SSL を使用します。

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL=True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#email-use-ssl

EMAIL_USE_TLSの方は、SMTPSを用いる際にTrueに指定します。